# New project, graph database?(Neo4j)

Tags: php, neo4j

I've this web project (in PHP) I wanna work on and I'm going to need alot of does any X (friend of friend) like Y kind of questions.

So I was crossing Neo4j but I'm not sure if it's Therese right approach.

I understand that the real world is like a graph but I'm going to have several regular tables with users, articles, comments, messages and so on. and a lot of regular questions like give me all info about this user (old relationship type of info )

can this be done?

servers, time and money is no problem as long as it will turn out cool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done, yes. But it will take you some time to figure out how graph based database work and how you can retrieve the data. First, you will only have vertices instead of tables. You can give your vertices properties and connect them with each other by so called edges.

On the technical side, you will need to use the REST-API of neo4j since they have no natural support for php (as far as I recall). But there's a cool tool called 'curl' which serves perfectly for the purpose to work with the rest api. You will also have to deal alot with JSON formatted data by the way;)

But again, it's a whole different approach then the regular relational one. You will probably need to read some tutorials and stuff before you can really get going.

Comment: I've no problem working with CURL or JSON ;)

Comment: There's a PHP wrapper btw... And it's pretty good. https://github.com/jadell/Neo4jPHP